# Will Google penalize my site for having duplicate categories between WordPress and Woo Commerce?

Tags: seo, wordpress, woocommerce

Any experience with same categories within posts and products (WP + Woocommerce)?

I would like to have a dedicated page for each category within posts, where I'll show couple of pictures and long description of the product. On the other hand I would like to have same categories in Shop (Woocommerce) showing products.

Will I be penalized by Google for duplicate categories?

Comment: Google rarely penalizes for duplicate content, especially when it is within your own site.   What Google will do is choose not to index a copy of duplicate pages.  See [What is duplicate content and how can I avoid being penalized for it on my site?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35652/what-is-duplicate-content-and-how-can-i-avoid-being-penalized-for-it-on-my-site)